# Best practice to compare local source (head) code with previous revision from svn

Tags: eclipse, file, svn, compare

I use svn for version control and Eclipse IDE.
When I have to do a code review I usually know the revision of the commit that I want to check.
What I'd like a have is a simple way to see the changes from the actual revision (aka "head") and the previous revision.
I know I can achive this via context menu "compare with" -> "revision..." and select the previous revision. But this is not very handy.
Is there a way (plugin?) to automatically open a view that compares "my version" of the file (with is head revision) with the version before when I open a java file in explorer view ?

This would be very helpful :-)

Thanks for your help!
Thorsten

Comment: It depends a bit on if you want to use SVN command line or if you have a graphical tool installed, but the easiest way to see a visual comparison is using a GUI SVN client with something like Araxis Merge or P4Merge installed and setup as the client's diff tool. If you are just using SVN from the terminal inside Eclipse you may prefer just to settle for a regular SVN diff. Essentially: `svn diff -r [revision1]:[revision2] [pathtofile]`

Comment: I know how to use the svn subversion/subclipse plugins in eclipse to do the compare. But this is not very handy to browse through the changes of a larger set of changed files. This is why I search for an easy way to do this inside eclipse.

Comment: Then I'd just use Araxis Merge or P4Merge with TortoiseSVN or another GUI for SVN.

Comment: Checkout these screen caps: http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en

Comment: I think if you want to install Araxis directly into Eclipse you need the Subclipse plugin but sounds like you want to avoid comparing using Subclipse plugin? http://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/integrating-with-other-applications.en#Eclipse